# Xamarin Forms - How to draw forms and fill them?

Tags: shapes

I'm a bit lost about how to make my final app design, so I'm coming today to speak about it !

Of course, I'm working on a cross platform solution (**PCL**), so if it does need a **CustomRenderer**, then I need to make **an Android, iOS & UWP renderers**.

What I want is hard to describe, so I'll try to explain as best as I can !

## There is the idea of form for our example:

[image]

As you can see, it's a 2D graphic, the left/right side are just something as a triangle. I have another triangle form at the top/mid which comes into the main 'rectangle'.

So, my first idea was to make a `point-to-point` graphic and then, fill the form made by a color. I think like that because of this **[question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/74012/uwp-xamarin-forms-custom-renderer-triangle)** asked on the Xamarin Forums.

However, I don't really know how can I do it.. In the link above, it's a UWP example and it doesn't work for me.. However, I'm not doing only UWP, I'm also making the app for Android & iOS, so what does exist to realize this kind of forms?

Also, I would prefer to code everything by my own, it gives me the possibility to keep everything up-to-date !

Thank for your help !

Comment: Can you please post how you resolved it?

Comment: I only did the UWP side